# Cocos2d-x iOS CocosDenshion Sound Player - Play at certain time MS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Using Cocos2d 3.

I am trying to work out how it is possible to play a sound or music from a certain time / millisecond within the loaded effect / sound.

Essentially a setTime method for the cocosDenshion class?

Anyone have any ideas? Or is this something I could contribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
auto sae = CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance();

someSprite->runAction(Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(time), CallFunc::create([&](){ sae->playEffect("mySound.wav"); })));
```

Wav should have smallest delay than other extension.

You can also preload it:

```
sae->preloadEffect("mySound.wav");
```

Still it's no guaranteed you will here it in perfect timing if you need high precision, but that's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the schedular after a certain a time like

### code

```
  this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::sound_method), 0.5);
void Helloworld::sound_method(float ty)
{     CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance( )->playEffect("Byuuton_yap.mp3");   }
```

here 0.5 is time ,sound_method call after 0.5 second.
i hope,this answer help someone